# Sorting array of structs (missing Len method)

Tags: arrays, sorting, go, struct

I have two structs defined as below:

```
// DuplicatedAd format
type DuplicatedAd struct {
    // Ad Identifier
    AdID int `form:"ad_id" json:"ad_id,omitempty" xml:"ad_id"`
    // Parameters of an Ad, can be empty
    AdParams string `form:"ad_params" json:"ad_params,omitempty" xml:"ad_params"`
    // Body of the Ad
    Body string `form:"body" json:"body,omitempty" xml:"body"`
    // Body Duplicate Percentage
    BodyScore float64 `form:"body_score" json:"body_score,omitempty" xml:"body_score"`
    // Category of the Ad
    Category int `form:"category" json:"category,omitempty" xml:"category"`
    // The ad uploaded main image
    Image string `form:"image,omitempty" json:"image,omitempty" xml:"image,omitempty"`
    // Ad Listing ID
    ListID int `form:"list_id" json:"list_id,omitempty" xml:"list_id"`
    // Listing time for the ad
    ListTime string `form:"list_time" json:"list_time,omitempty" xml:"list_time"`
    // the ad Phone number
    Phone string `form:"phone,omitempty" json:"phone,omitempty" xml:"phone,omitempty"`
    // Region of the Ad
    Region int `form:"region" json:"region,omitempty" xml:"region"`
    // Ad Status
    Status string `form:"status" json:"status,omitempty" xml:"status"`
    // Subject of the Ad
    Subject string `form:"subject" json:"subject,omitempty" xml:"subject"`
    // Subject Duplicate Percentage
    SubjectScore float64 `form:"subject_score" json:"subject_score,omitempty" xml:"subject_score"`
    // Type of the Ad
    Type string `form:"type" json:"type,omitempty" xml:"type"`
    // Total Score
    TotalScore float64 `form:"total_score" json:"total_score,omitempty" xml:"total_score"`
}

// CpResponse format
type CpResponse struct {
    // Number of doublets
    Count int `json:"count"`
    // The Doublet Ads to show
    Duplicated []DuplicatedAd `json:"duplicated"`
}
```

i'm defining a variable `var DuplicatedAds = CpResponse{}`and in a loop i'm appending some results to it as follow:

```
DuplicatedAds.Duplicated = append(DuplicatedAds.Duplicated, t)
DuplicatedAds.Count = len(DuplicatedAds.Duplicated)
```

i wish that the `DuplicatedAds.Duplicated` be sorted by `TotalScore`.

i'm new to golang, so after a little research i found out that i must implement theses three functions before i can sort

```
func (slice DuplicatedAd) Len() int {
    return len(slice)
}

func (slice DuplicatedAd) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return slice[i].TotalScore < slice[j].TotalScore
}

func (slice DuplicatedAd) Swap(i, j int) {
    slice[i], slice[j] = slice[j], slice[i]
}
```

but when i try to compile i get this errors:

```
./duplicates.go:165: cannot use DuplicatedAds.Duplicated (type []DuplicatedAd) as type sort.Interface in argument to sort.Sort:
    []DuplicatedAd does not implement sort.Interface (missing Len method)
./types.go:68: invalid argument slice (type DuplicatedAd) for len
./types.go:72: invalid operation: slice[i] (type DuplicatedAd does not support indexing)
./types.go:72: invalid operation: slice[j] (type DuplicatedAd does not support indexing)
./types.go:76: invalid operation: slice[i] (type DuplicatedAd does not support indexing)
./types.go:76: invalid operation: slice[j] (type DuplicatedAd does not support indexing)
./types.go:76: invalid operation: slice[i] (type DuplicatedAd does not support indexing)
```

How could i have an `CpResponse` object which his `Duplicated` array is sorted by `DuplicatedAd.TotalScore` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from Go 1.8, you can use the following function to sort your slice:

```
sort.Slice(DuplicatedAds.Duplicated, func(i int, j int) bool {
    return DuplicatedAds.Duplicated[i].TotalScore < DuplicatedAds.Duplicated[j].TotalScore
})
```

You don't need to define those three functions up there anymore (`Len`, `Less` and `Swap`). Notice how we used the same implementation of `Len` as a parameter of `sort.Slice`.

Comment: Thanks, i forgot to mention that i'm using version 1.5.
but i tried `slice.Duplicated[i].TotalScore` like you mentioned instead of  `slice[i].TotalScore` like i did, and it works

Answer (score 0):

cd1 offers a good solution. As for the reason your methods aren't working, it's because they're operating on a single struct and not a slice of structs.

You would want something more like this where each method works on the DuplicatedAdSlice type rather than the DuplicatedAd type.

```
type DuplicatedAdSlice []DuplicatedAd // Type alias

func (slice DuplicatedAdSlice) Len() int {
    return len(slice)
}
```

And update the CpResponse struct to use the type alias

```
// The Doublet Ads to show
Duplicated DuplicatedAdSlice `json:"duplicated"`
```